# Installed package curl and got a postfix error!? How do I fix postfix now?

Tags: installation, apt, postfix

I have a couple questions related to the error below:

Why was postfix reconfigured when I installed curl? Is this normal?

What do I need to do to resolve the postfix error mentioned?

```
sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 403kB of archives.
After this operation, 729kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main libcurl3 7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3 [206kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main curl 7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3 [197kB]
Fetched 403kB in 3s (102kB/s)
Selecting previously deselected package libcurl3.
(Reading database ... 48741 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libcurl3 (from .../libcurl3_7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package curl.
Unpacking curl (from .../curl_7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb) ...
Setting up postfix (2.5.1-2ubuntu1.4) ...
setting inet_protocols: all

Postfix is now set up with the changes above.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
postalias: fatal: open /etc/postfix/aliases.db: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing postfix (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcurl3 (7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...

Setting up curl (7.18.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc6 ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Was postfix working before the attempt to install curl?

Comment: Yes, postfix was working before. It is still working now. And curl works too. But I have not rebooted yet. Should I run dpkg reconfigure? What else should I do to ensure there are no problems. BTW, I have mailman installed.

Comment: Might try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to see if there are still issues (it would generally suggest `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix problems if this is the case).  I don't know for sure, but `sudo newaliases` might also be useful for diagnosing issues at this point.

Comment: I just ran `sudo newaliases`, `sudo postalias /etc/aliases` and `sudo /etc/init.d/mailman restart` and there were no errors. And mailman still works.

Comment: I did the upgrade and there were no problems. It did not suggest `apt-get install -f`. Maybe everything is OK. If you want to provide an answer I'll accept it in a day or so (once I see if there are indeed no problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was able to ignore the error. Apparently nothing was broken.